# Не получается нажать кнопку "Отправить" в Google Forms через Selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, google-forms

Имеется вот такой код на Python:

```
from time import sleep

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("-incognito")
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
ser = Service("d:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=option)

browser.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdMxDauEatgZGCVoAG3XGuDaCFs9emRPSx9hLUkgtTOf47pqg/viewform")

textboxes = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")
radiobuttons = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelWrapper")
checkboxes = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxInnerBox")
submitbutton = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "appsMaterialWizButtonPaperbuttonRipple")
sleep(3)

textboxes[0].send_keys("Hello World")
radiobuttons[2].click()
checkboxes[1].click()
submitbutton.click()
#button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(submitbutton))
#button.click()
```

При запуске выводит сообщение об ошибке:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\my\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    submitbutton.click()
  File "D:\my\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 81, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "D:\my\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 710, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "D:\my\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\my\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)
```

Пробовал заменить

```
submitbutton.click()
```

на

```
button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(submitbutton))
button.click()
```

При этом ругается на таймаут:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\my\main.py", line 27, in <module>
    button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(submitbutton))
  File "D:\my\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Подскажите, что делать, в какую сторону рыть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что именно вас интересует?

Answer (score 1):

Ругается на таймаут потому что элемент не является кликабельным. Такое бывает если, например, ипользуются псевдоэлементы ::after, элемент имеет размер 0 и не может быть нажат. Есть пару вариантов как обойти это дело:

1. Попробовать найти другой элемент выше или ниже по дереву и нажать на него.
2. Использовать js click, тебе нужно написать функцию типа такой:

```
    def js_click(self, element):
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("myid")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Можно проверить еще есть ли возможность нажать на элемент через action chain